# why Sagemaker Processing have several ouputs

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have been using AWS Sagemaker for years.

I don't understand why processing jobs can have several outputs ? In what kind of scenario, can you use more than one output destination ?

When I say several outputs I refer to [ProcessingOutputConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ProcessingOutputConfig.html) containing an array

Answer (score 0):

A common reason to use SageMaker Processing is to do a train/test/validation split for machine learning

So, you'd want to output your training data to one S3 path, your test data to another, and your validation to yet another